# How to search in Elasticsearch by matching multiple fields with different priorities?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index with two fields: “title” and “product_titles”. I want to search for documents that match a query string in both fields, but give more priority to the “title” field. For example, if I search for “A B”, I want the documents that have “A B” in the “title” field to rank higher than the documents that have “A B” in the “product_titles” field. I also want to consider the number of occurrences of the query string in the “product_titles” field as a secondary factor for ranking.

Here is a sample of expected result sorted by score in JSON format:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "A B ...", // title matches
    "product_titles": ["anything", "anything"]
  },
  {
    "title": "anything",
    "product_titles": ["....A B....", " ... A B", "A B ..."] // three matches
  },
  {
    "title": "anything",
    "product_titles": ["....A B....", " ... A B"] // two matches
  },
  {
    "title": "A", // partial match
    "product_titles": ["anything"] // no match
  }
]
```

Comment: have you ever tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21570963/21829520)?

Comment: Yes, but in my project, the number of occurrences of "product_titles" is very important. It seems Elasticsearch's scoring doesn't take into account the number of occurrences when calculating the score.

Comment: "A B" and "AB" are two different strings. If you are looking for "A_B", I don't think there will be any document with three matches in `product_titles`.

Comment: No, it was my mistake. There is no "AB"; it should be "A B". I have fixed it.
@CharchitKapoor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of achieving this, but you'll have to re-index your data. Also, test it thoroughly, it works with the data you provided.

Create the mapping for `title` field initially, and also provide a similarity function, which defines how score will be computed for `title` field. Like this:

```
PUT /dummy-index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "similarity": {
      "scripted_tf": {
        "type": "scripted",
        "script": {
          "source": "return Math.pow(doc.freq, query.boost)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "similarity": "scripted_tf"
      },
      "product_titles": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this query, we are providing a similarity function for `title` field. In which we are raising the `score` for `title` using `power` function, rather than multiplying.

Then, after indexing the data, the following query gives desired results.

```
GET dummy-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "A B",
      "fields": ["title^2", "product_titles"]
    }
  }
}
```